# Do we have a formula (which maybe related to integral or probability) of $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}] (\omega)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

My lecture note defines conditional expectation as follows:

---

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-sigma field of $\mathcal{F}$. If $X$ is an integrable random variable, then the conditional expectation of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$ is any integrable random variable $Z$ which satisfies the following two properties:

**(CE1)** $Z$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

**(CE2)** $$\forall \Lambda \in \mathcal{G}: \int_{\Lambda} Z \, d \mathbb{P}=\int_{\Lambda} X \, d \mathbb{P}$$

We denote $Z$ by $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}]$.

---

Let $X$ be an integrable random variable and $\mathcal G$ a sub-sigma field.

I would like to ask if we can deduce a formula (which maybe related to integral or probability) of $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}] (\omega)$ from **(CE1)** and **(CE2)**.

Thank you so much!

Comment: In general, $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}]$ is defined only up to sets of measure zero.  If singleton $\{\omega\}$ has measure zero, then changing $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}]$ on $\omega$ makes no difference.  If you have studied measure theory, you may like to think of $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}]$ as an example of a Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Comment: Hi @GEdgar, if $X$ is the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_\Lambda$, can we have a formula for $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_\Lambda | \mathcal{G}] (\omega)$ without Radon-Nikodym derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mu(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the *regular conditional distribution* of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$, then for an integrable function $g$,
$$
\mathsf{E}[g(X)\mid \mathcal{G}](\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)\mu(\omega,dx) \quad\text{a.s.}
$$

Comment: Hi @d.k.o, if $X$ is the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_\Lambda$, can we have a formula for $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_\Lambda | \mathcal{G}] (\omega)$ without regular conditional distribution?

Comment: What kind of formula are you looking for?